# Cocoa: for NSView,how to make a subview outside of its bound show,not be cut a half?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, subview

[image: the blue rectangle is the textfield control]

I want to make the TextField object with the string value "Default" show its whole appearance,not be cut a half,so how should I do?

Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the "wrong resizing attributes on either the scrollview or its superview." http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Mar/msg00357.html

Comment: Thanks guy!Just now I got a way to fix this issue.first,you should make a subclass for from the NSTextfield,and override the method: wantsDefaultClipping,give a return value: NO,and in the current view(parent view) also override this method and also return NO,then the textfield can show the whole appearance.

Comment: Are you adding this in XCode or creating programmatically. I think there is a much better way then to do this without messing with clipping regions. For example, use `[textField sizeToFit];` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using autolayout and that’s NSTextField, just make sure it’s not height constrained in Interface Builder and it’ll always resize automatically to fit a line of text.

If you’re not using autolayout then use @boyfarrell’s -sizeToFit.

You don’t want to try to get a view to draw outside its bounds, because AppKit isn’t set up for this and so it’ll fail in a huge variety of ways. For instance, the view won’t be called and asked to redraw when the area outside its bounds is dirtied, so you’ll end up sometimes not drawing the part outside the bounds. Also, the views behind the view won’t always be cleared for the outside areas, so you’ll end up overdrawing the outside bits as well, resulting in SUPER-BOLDFACE text.

Comment: Just try it [textFieldObj sizeFit]; but not work.Maybe I lost some factor.